# JavaScript IE8 Error - Object doesnt support This Property

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

IE 8 says: it doesn't support this property or method:

Code is here (Error in coming in this whole part):

```
$('li').has('ul').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').css('visibility','visible');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').css('visibility','hidden');
})
```

This code is a part of this function:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1) < 7) {
    $('li').has('ul').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').css('visibility','visible');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').css('visibility','hidden');
    })
}
```

What is wrong with this.. please help.

Comment: Does it occur when you mouseover or when you run the code?

Comment: That's not where the error is coming from.

Comment: The error shows in IE8 only.. when document is loaded.. I get "Done, but with error" at the bottom of IE8.. when I start IE8 Debugger, it points me to that code

Comment: if the browser is IE8 as you have mentioned in question title, the inside code will never be executed-- as you have put the condition "$.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1) < 7"

Comment: it may not be executed.. but IE debugger showing error :).. it debugs whole script.. no matter if it for him or not :)

Comment: Maybe try taking out parts at a time and see which exactly causes it. For example, completely take out everything **inside** of the `if` statement, so that you can see if the `if` statement is the problem for whatever reason. Then, try **not** putting anything inside of the event handlers (one at a time). Then, try filling in each event handler individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but small correction use `$('li ul')` instead of `$('li').has('ul')`